# PHP Session not getting updated in FireFox

Tags: session, firefox

I am facing a strange error. It is related to updating the php session.

I have a site whose login/logout works perfectly in chrome,safari and IE etc. But in firefox it is not working. When I login using firefox, the logout button seems to be dead or something. It just doesnt let me logout. Even if I manually type the logout link, it still doesnt do anything and keeps me logged in. I am not doing anything complex at all.

Any ideas why the same code works in chrome, IE and safari but not in firefox?

Let me know,
Thanks.

============================LOGOUT CODE===============================

```
public function logout() {
    $this->session->unset_userdata('smallpoint_username');
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect(base_url() . 'forum/update_session.php?hasher = ' . time() . time() . time() . time() . time() . time() . '&&nohasher=' . time() . time() . time() . time() . time() . time() . '&&op=2', 'location', 301);
}
```

================SESSION SETTING CODE in LOGIN===============================

```
 $session_array = array(
                        'smallpoint_username' => $insertData['username'],
                        'smallpoint_full_name' => $insertData['full_name'],
                        'smallpoint_user_type' => $insertData['user_type'],
                        'smallpoint_user_id' => $userData['id'],
                        'smallpoint_user_snap' => '',
                        'is_logged_in' => 1,
                    );
                    $this->session->set_userdata($session_array);
                    redirect(base_url() . 'forum/update_session.php?hasher = ' . time() . time() . time() . time() . time() . time() . '&&nohasher=' . time() . time() . time() . time() . time() . time() . '&&thisisid=' . $userData['id'] . '&&thisisrole=' . $insertData['role'] . '&&thisisname=' . $insertData['username'] . '&&op=1', 'location', 301);
```

=====================update_session.php======================

```
 session_start();
 require 'includes.php';
 if ($_GET['op'] == 1) {
     $_SESSION[TABLES_PREFIX . 'sforum_logged_in'] = true;
     $_SESSION[TABLES_PREFIX . 'sforum_user_id'] = $_GET['thisisid'];
     $_SESSION[TABLES_PREFIX . 'sforum_user_role'] = $_GET['thisisrole'];
     $_SESSION[TABLES_PREFIX . 'sforum_user_username'] = $_GET['thisisname'];
 } else {
     unset($_SESSION[TABLES_PREFIX . 'sforum_logged_in']);
     unset($_SESSION[TABLES_PREFIX . 'sforum_user_id']);
     unset($_SESSION[TABLES_PREFIX . 'sforum_user_role']);
     unset($_SESSION[TABLES_PREFIX . 'sforum_user_username']);

     setcookie(TABLES_PREFIX . COOKIE_NAME, "", time() - 3600);
 }
 header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Comment: Are you using sessions with cookies, or just cookies? Can you post some code? Notice how both approaches require the browser to accept a cookie?

Comment: I added the code too. Looks like it is using cookies as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following to your code.

```
session_save_path("/tmp");
session_start();
```

I got the same problem in firefox and it works fine

```
session_save_path("/tmp"); // CREATE this Folder in the root
session_start();
require 'includes.php';
if ($_GET['op'] == 1) {
 $_SESSION[TABLES_PREFIX . 'sforum_logged_in'] = true;
 $_SESSION[TABLES_PREFIX . 'sforum_user_id'] = $_GET['thisisid'];
 $_SESSION[TABLES_PREFIX . 'sforum_user_role'] = $_GET['thisisrole'];
 $_SESSION[TABLES_PREFIX . 'sforum_user_username'] = $_GET['thisisname'];
} else {
 unset($_SESSION[TABLES_PREFIX . 'sforum_logged_in']);
 unset($_SESSION[TABLES_PREFIX . 'sforum_user_id']);
 unset($_SESSION[TABLES_PREFIX . 'sforum_user_role']);
 unset($_SESSION[TABLES_PREFIX . 'sforum_user_username']);

 setcookie(TABLES_PREFIX . COOKIE_NAME, "", time() - 3600);
}
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Comment: where do I add this? while deleting the session or while setting it?